# Javascript change image/background image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

Having some problems with some dynamic stuff.

I have the following JS function which gets run when I run a button. It shows (upon postback) a nice css alert then runs the function.

```
function totop(sender, args) {
   window.scroll(0, 0);
   document.getElementById("wait").innerHTML = "<br/><div class='alert-box notice' id='spinner' ><span>Validating : </span>One moment please.</div>";
$('#spinner').css("background-image", "url(images/ajax.gif)");
}
```

The idea is that it changes the background picture to ajax.gif (spinner) but the ajax.gif does not show. Not unless on the button onClick you add "return false;"

Why does jQuery not update images on the fly? even tried it with vanilla javascript too, same thing.

Comment: add a fiddle, that will make it better.

Comment: try background instead of beackground-image. **Off topic** : By the way you use a weird mix of jquery selector and standard javascript. Why don't you use `$("#wait").html('some text');`

Comment: looks like code is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/22cm3txp/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the image ajax.gif not located where you expect.
Try to open it in the browser. Maybe if you try the following:

```
$('#spinner').css("background-image", "url('../images/ajax.gif)'");
```

This may be will help.

Comment: no, it does exist. If you use Return false; on the button then it stops post back so you can perform an F12 on the element and it does exists when you click on the url.

Comment: Hmmm. $('#spinner').css("background-image", "url('../images/ajax.gif)' !important;"); Does this change anything?

Comment: tried this, but doesn't work. Funny thing is if I set the DIV in the HTML page, for example.. <div class='alert-box notice' id='spinner' ><span>Validating : </span>One moment please.</div>"; the GIF shows, because the background-image of that div is "background: #e3f7fc url('../images/ajax.gif') no-repeat 10px 50%;", but to show that exact same div within javascript (using innerHTML), the div shows Ok but without the background image. Still strange!

Comment: $('#spinner').css("background-image", "url('./images/ajax.gif')") And with this have any effect?